# When does Firefox create a new inner window

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

For a Firefox extension, I intercept http requests and http responses, I get the `LoadContext` and find out the inner window ID & outer window ID.

The http request I intercepted is for a URL to replace the current view, i.e., the http response will replace the current webpage in the current tab, i.e. it will result in a new inner window.

When I intercept the request and the response, I still do not know its new inner window id, which can only be known with "content-document-global-created" event.

The event sequence is

```
http-on-modify-request  innerID(current):outerID  
http-on-examine-merged-response innerID(current):outerID  
content-document-global-created   (innerID is new):outerID
```

If the current page will not be replaced by the new http response (e.g. an image, or Javascript), then the `LoadContext.associatedWindow` gives the current window is good.

But if the page is going to be replaced by the new http response (e.g. a new html page), I would hope the `LoadContext.associatedWindow` is a new window. Though before the response is really received, it is unnecessary to replace the current page with blank.

I guess when the request is sent, Firefox knows whether its response will replace the current web page, so a new `DOMWindow` should be created and a new inner window id should be assigned.

Any idea?

Comment: Nice question, I like you sharing your research on the event sequence.

Comment: By the way, the content-document-global-created event becomes useless for me since it is too late. I deem the current firefox implementation is not good/right so firefox will have to change the loadcontext upen a response is received. Changing the loadcontext is not logically right. I filled a bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1029344 though they do not agree with me. @Noitidart

Comment: I am very sure eventually they will change to the way I proposed, maybe 6 month or maybe 1 year. As long as more people are using the LoadContext, they will find out LoadContext.associatedWindow could & should be set to the right one, rather than to change it later on. Let's see how much time this change will take.

Comment: Nice work on bugzilla file. nice drive/passion

Answer (score 1):

> I guess when the request is sent, Firefox knows whether its response will replace the current web page, so a new DOMWindow should be created and a new inner window id should be assigned.

That assumption is incorrect. That would depend on the response received, if any. Something could block/cancel the request after it is issued, or the server might not return any data at all (or an add-on just "eats" the data), or return invalid data or issue invalid redirects, etc.

Hence there will be only a new window (and inner ID) once the browser decided to actually create a new window **after** receiving at least part of the final response (enough to know how to proceed).

Since you didn't elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve ultimately, I'll stop here..

> If the current page will not be replaced by the new http response (e.g. an image, or Javascript), then the `LoadContext.associatedWindow` gives the current window is good.

Technically, this assumption is incorrect as well, as not all requests actually have an associated window in the first place.

Comment: It is very nice to read your answer. However, I do not agree with you at all. I opened a ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1029344 I put more info there. Though people do not agree with me. For your 2nd part, all the requests from a webpage or from the user should always have an associated window, at least, no harm. Of course, requests initiated by chrome code (firefox itself or any extension), no associated window is needed.

Comment: For your 1st part, I know what you described is the current implementation,but for any request initiated by the user, there is no harm to create the inner window before sending the request though not need to replace the current window right away. Once no replacement is needed, just throw that window away.This is the right way to do it.At present, when a new window is needed, then a blank window is created, and then when the response comes, another created to replace the 1st one. Also the current implementation will have to change the loadcontext upon its response is received which is not right

Comment: There is nothing to agree or disagree with here. I didn't express any opinion, just facts. There is also no point argue about the current implementation with me: neither did I create it nor am I responsible for it.

Comment: You did say my assumption is incorrect, so you did have opinions which is different from mine. Please do not be afraid of disagreement. Unless you have changed your opinions? @nmaier